# Can't control a css element that shares a css class with another element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, class, display

[FYI: Doing a Udemy tutorial challenge]

Here is the html. It displays 2 dice. As you can see, they share the class 'dice.' Then each die also has its own class for controlling individual items, 'dice1' and 'dice2' respectively.

```
<img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice 1" class="dice dice1">
<img src="dice-5.png" alt="Dice 2" class="dice dice2">
```

Here is the css for all three of these classes, 'dice', 'dice1', 'dice2.' As you can see, the 'dice1' and 'dice2' classes merely control the vertical position on screen.

```
.dice {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
}

.dice1 {
    top: 260px;
}

.dice2 {
    top: 150px;
}
```

At the beginning of this dice game, neither dice should be visible. For this I am using Javascript to control the display with the following code.

```
document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
```

For some reason this ONLY works on dice1. It does not work on dice2. If I add an additional line of code specifying class 'dice2', dice2 will also disappear. However, selecting the class 'dice' SHOULD select them BOTH. Why is this not working?

Comment: don't edit the question to add *solved*, accept the answer that solves your problem

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm doing a Udemy course and in their question and answer section, they ask people to edit the question to include [SOLVED] if someone has provided the correct solution. I assumed it would be helpful for people for me to do so here.

Comment: I just marked it as accepted. I don't know if I'm allowed to do that or if it needs to be someone with more points than I have.

Comment: @Siggytron: on your questions, _only_ you can accept answers. It is not mandatory to do so, but it is nice - it rewards helpful people, and shows other readers what was most useful in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

> The Document method querySelector() **returns the first Element** within
>   the document

use querySelectorAll:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dice').forEach( dice_Item=>dice_Item.style.display = 'none' );
```

Comment: QuerySelectorAll return an array of elements. This is not jQuery, and they can't not apply a method on each elements, you will have to add this method ( forEach ) by yourself

Comment: Forget jQuery, it was created when JS has not the same syntax on the different browsers. This no more the case today :
today ES6, tomorrow ES7 with many new functionally.  jQuery is still staying from 2014 (last release 2016), and may not go further (?). Learn typeScript, VueJS, React, Webpack, nodeJS...
there so many things arround JS...